# Undocumented overload of string.Split()?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, intellisense

According to both Intellisense and [MSDN doc on string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), there are no parameterless overloads of string.Split.  Yet if I type in

```
string[] foo = bar.Split();
```

It compiles. And it works.  I have verified this in both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010.  In both cases intellisense does not show the parameterless overload.

Is there a reason for this?  Are there any other missing overloads from the MSDN/Intellisense docs?  Usually browsing through overloads in intellisense is how I best determine which overload to use.  I'd hate to think I am missing other available options throughout the .Net framework.

EDIT: as shown above, it splits on whitespace.

Comment: ummm - neil - did you ever get an answer to your question? lolzalot

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is because Split has a params overload. Giving no parameters is the same as giving an empty array. In other words, you are calling [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx).

```
"some text".Split();
```

Is the same as:

```
"some text".Split(new char[0]);
```

Here is [the documentation on the params keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx). As you probably know, it is used for giving a method a variable number of parameters. That number may be zero.

Comment: Lots of good answers but I'll accept this once since it was the first.

Answer (score 8):

I bet it's matching this `String.Split` overload:

```
public string[] Split(params char[] separator)
{
    return this.Split(separator, 0x7fffffff, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```

0 arguments is acceptable for this function.  Given no separators, [it defaults to white space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx).

Comment: +1 "defaults to white space"... thanks, I could have swore it was a comma, but then my code didn't work as expected.  Must have been remembering Java.

Answer (score 5):

Actually what you are calling here is *string.Split(params char[] separator)*

[params (C# reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

*You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified in the parameter declaration, or an array of arguments of the specified type. **You also can send no arguments**.*

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with a weakness of exposing parameters as 'params array[]'.  See the signature of the following method as documented in MSDN, so obviously you are passing in an empty array.

```
public string[] Split(params char[] separator)
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.Split()` has a number of overloads; you are correct that none of those overloads is parameter-less, however, one of them is varadic: `String.Split(params char[])`. The variable length portion of the argument list can be any number of arguments, including zero -- that is the overload you're invoking here.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string[] Split(params char[] separator)
```

params is 0 or more