# Why does .NET string.Empty.Split() return one item containing a space character?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm curious, why does .NET `string.Empty.Split()` return one item containing a space character?

Comment: might be a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906621/undocumented-overload-of-string-split

Comment: **It doesn't.** It returns an array containing 1 empty string. There is no space character in that first item. Can you tell us why you think there is? What kind of tool/code do you use to show the content of that first item that tells you there is a space there?

Comment: You can get rid of this space if you pass this option `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Answer (score 1):

One small correction in your statement. `string.Empty.Split()` doesn't return one item with a space character, but it returns an item with empty string. This is because the method split() when it has no arguments, considers white space as the delimiter. But there is no white space either in the `string.Empty`. So it just returns the string.Empty as such in the 1st item of the output array.

Answer (score 0):

`string.Empty.Split()` returns a string array which has the value `string.Empty` at the first position. What would you expect?

**Additional Information:** Everything before the first match is returned as the first element. If there is no match, the string itself is returned at the first position.

Comment: OK, the combination of split and join have confused me:

```var strings = string.Empty.Split();```
```var list = new List<string>(strings) {"another"};```
```Console.WriteLine($"'{string.Join(" ", list)}'");```

This prepends a single space. But where does it come from?

Comment: Ah, if I'd understood what the split was doing I wouldn't have been surprised to get a space at the beginning of my joined string.

Comment: So your question is answered?

Comment: I think it is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you provide nothing as a seperators to the `Split` method, it [uses whitespaces by default](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,10c5b3e0ef2b8a70):

```
private unsafe int MakeSeparatorList(char[] separator, ref int[] sepList) {
   ...
   if (separator == null || separator.Length ==0) {
      ...
      // If they passed null or an empty string, look for whitespace.
```

So when you call `string.Empty.Split()`, you are trying to split an emtpy string by whitespace characters. There aren't any, so the method returns the whole string as the only result. Exactly like calling `"Hello!".Split` will return `string[] { "Hello!" }`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't [see](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RBo1dR)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ehh \"" + string.Empty.Split()[0] + "\"");
    }
}
```

returns:

```
ehh ""
```